# сканировать txt файл в С

Tags: c

в текстовом файле записана "таблица" в таком формате

```
1.name surname              |2.9.1904   |48 89 53 67
```

и структура вот такая

```
struct people{
char name[NAME];
int age;
int data[4];};
```

как считать `name surname` в `name`, `1904` в `age`, а `48 89 53 67` в`int data[4]`
я пробовал

```
    fscanf(table, ".%s|", data[i].name);
    fscanf(table, ".%d ", &data[i].age);
    fscanf(table, "%2d %2d %2d %2d", &data[i].marks[0], 
    &data[i].marks[1], &data[i].marks[2], &data[i].marks[3]);
```

но выходит белиберда. да, я знаю, что name так не получишь, но что не так с таким 
форматом?

Comment: так можно в фсканф насколько я знаю сразу шаблон написать, а потом все переменные передать в одну строку. То есть вместо 3 сделать 1

Comment: @Herrgott  но там десятки строк такого формата и мне нужно игнорировать  некоторые записи, которые каждый раз разные, разве что создавать дополнительные переменные

Comment: ты не понял. Я не знаю си, но в плюсах, насколько я помню, неограниченное число аргументов в scanf передается. Я имел ввиду что можно написать один `fscanf(table, "template", data[i].name, data[i].age, ...)` и тогда не будет "белиберды" на выходе

Comment: @Herrgott  да, неограниченное, но так каждый раз нужно писать новый формат т.к пробелы и числа, которые нужно игнорировать

Comment: но если есть какая-та общая логика, то написать регекс можно. Либо если это разовая обработка, убрать все пробелы и табы и привести к общему виду

Comment: а вообще можешь поискать либу для csv

Comment: 1. Насколько я помню, функции scanf() не очень любят лишние символы в форматной строке, поэтому я бы убрал всякие точки и вертикальные черточки. 2. Имя и фамилию так за 1 раз не получить - надо либо считывать в две промежуточные переменные и потом склеивать,  либо см. п.3.  3. Думаю, было бы удобнее считать сразу всю строку (fgets()), а потом ее разбирать через strtok() или через регулярные выражения, как уже советовали.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scanf достаточно мощная штука в умелых руках. Вот рабочий пример (для данных входных данных)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int id;
    char name[100];
    char surname[100];
    int day, month, year;
    int data[4];
    int x = scanf("%i . %s %s %*[ \t|]%i.%i.%i %*[ |] %i %i %i %i",&id, name, surname, &day, &month, &year, &data[0], &data[1], &data[2], &data[3]);
    printf("x = %d\n", x); // выведем, сколько распарсилось полей
    // и сами поля
    printf("id = %i\nname = %s\nsurname = %s\ndate %i %i %i\n", id, name, surname, day, month, year);
    printf("data = %i %i %i %i\n", data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Строка "форматирования" (или все таки "форматированного считывания"?) достаточно сложная, но проста. Разберем по кусочкам

```
`%i .` прочитать число и точку. Тут все просто и по документации.
`%s %s` прочитать два слова. Слова разделяются пробелами.
`%*[ \t|]` это странная строка, которая говорит, читай любыме символы в скобках (пробел, табуляция и палочка (пайп)) процент-звездочка в начале говорит "читай, но не вноси в переменную".
`%i.%i.%i` тут все просто - прочитать 3 целых числа через точку.
`%*[ \t|]` тут аналогично.
`%i %i %i %i` здесь снова все просто - 4 целых числа.
```

конструкция с квадратными скобками немного специфична и раньше ее компилятры не поддерживали. Но gcc точно поддерживает, и vs вроде как тоже. Но нужно проверить.

Comment: Может быть "безопасней" (в плане обнаружения ошибок в формате и продолжения разбора) читать файл построчно и использовать sscanf?

Comment: Может. Но может это одноразовая задача. Я там не даром сделал вывод кол-ва полей.